# Wordpress Post Navigation Thumbnail Link

Tags: wordpress

I have the following code which displays the WordPress post navigation but only the title links to the post. Is there a way I can make the whole thing link to the post instead?

```
previous_post_link( '<div class="prev">'.$prevThumbnail.'<div class="prev-post-header">Previous</div>%link</div>', '%title' );
```

Answer (score 0):

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_previous_post
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_post

```
<?php
$prev_post = get_previous_post();
$next_post = get_next_post();
if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $prev_post->guid ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $prev_post->guid, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        <?php echo $prev_post->post_title ?>
    </a>
<?php endif;
if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink( $next_post->ID ) ); ?>">
        <?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail( $next_post->ID, 'thumbnail' ); ?>
        <?php echo esc_attr( $next_post->post_title ); ?>
    </a>
<?php endif; ?>
```